# Non-zero Riemann tensors for the BTZ solution without charge or angular momentum

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, spacetime-dimensions

Can someone tell me which are the non-zero components of the Riemann tensor for the [BTZ solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTZ_black_hole) with the **absence of charge and angular momentum**? I tried searching it up but couldn't find any references. I'm using the metric $$ds^{2}=-{\frac {(r^{2}-r_{+}^{2})(r^{2}-r_{-}^{2})}{l^{2}r^{2}}}dt^{2}+{\frac {l^{2}r^{2}dr^{2}}{(r^{2}-r_{+}^{2})(r^{2}-r_{-}^{2})}}+r^{2}\left(d\phi -{\frac {r_{+}r_{-}}{lr^{2}}}dt\right)^{2}$$
where the mass is defined $$M={\frac {r_{+}^{2}+r_{-}^{2}}{l^{2}}}$$
and it would be best appreciated if the solutions are written in terms of the mass $M$. Thanks.

Comment: BTZ metric is locally isometric to the AdS spacetime, so the Riemann tensor has the form $Riem= C (g_… g_… - g_… g_…)$ and its nonzero components are easily found through that. “Absence of charge and angular momentum” means that $r_{-}=0$.